# Continuous Performance Testing in .NET

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, performance-testing

I have a large a codebase (that exposed RPC operations, workers, asp.net website) that I would like to test is performance of public operations.

How can I do this in .NET?

1. Which perf testing framework you recommend for .NET?
2. How to run this in TeamCity as part of my CI?

Comment: You want to test performance regression ? We had a similar needs few months ago, I looked at [tobami/codespeed](https://github.com/tobami/codespeed/) but it didn't completely fit our requirements. I finally built an application from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JMeter it is supported by TeamCity?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, JMeter is for asp.net, I am trying to create performance regression tests for the .net workers code that I have.